# parallel code execution python2.7 ndb

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

in my app i for one of the handler i need to get a bunch of entities and execute a function for each one of them.

i have the keys of all the enities i need. after fetching them i need to execute 1 or 2 instance methods for each one of them and this slows my app down quite a bit. doing this for 100 entities takes around 10 seconds which is way to slow.

im trying to find a way to get the entities and execute those functions in parallel to save time but im not really sure which way is the best.

i tried the _post_get_hook but the i have a future object and need to call get_result() and execute the function in the hook which works kind of ok in the sdk but gets a lot of 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python objec' but i can't really undestand why and the error message is not really elaborate.

is the Pipeline api or ndb.Tasklets what im searching for?

atm im going by trial and error but i would be happy if someone could lead me to the right direction.

**EDIT**

my code is something similar to a filesystem, every folder contains other folders and files. The path of the Collections set on another entity so to serialize a collection entity i need to get the referenced entity and get the path. On a Collection the serialized_assets() function is slower the more entities it contains. If i could execute a serialize function for each contained asset side by side it would speed things up quite a bit.

```
class Index(ndb.Model):
    path = ndb.StringProperty()


class Folder(ndb.Model):
    label = ndb.StringProperty()
    index = ndb.KeyProperty()

    # contents is a list of keys of contaied Folders and Files
    contents = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)    

    def serialized_assets(self):
        assets = ndb.get_multi(self.contents)

        serialized_assets = []
        for a in assets:
            kind = a._get_kind()
            assetdict = a.to_dict()
            if kind == 'Collection':
                assetdict['path'] = asset.path
                # other operations ...
            elif kind == 'File':
                assetdict['another_prop'] = asset.another_property
                # ...
            serialized_assets.append(assetdict)

        return serialized_assets

    @property
    def path(self):
        return self.index.get().path


class File(ndb.Model):
    filename = ndb.StringProperty()
    # other properties....

    @property
    def another_property(self):
        # compute something here
        return computed_property
```

**EDIT2:**

```
    @ndb.tasklet
    def serialized_assets(self, keys=None):
        assets = yield ndb.get_multi_async(keys)
        raise ndb.Return([asset.serialized for asset in assets])
```

is this tasklet code ok?

Comment: Are the functions slow because they do a lot of computation, or because they wait on RPCs? If the former, threads or the taskqueue are your best bet; if the latter, NDB tasklets are what you want. Elaborate and I can post an answer demonstrating either one.

Comment: @NickJohnson mostly its waiting for RPCs. i edited the question with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since most of the execution time of your functions are spent waiting for RPCs, NDB's async and tasklet support is your best bet. That's described in some detail [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async). The simplest usage for your requirements is probably to use the `ndb.map` function, like this (from the docs):

```
@ndb.tasklet
def callback(msg):
  acct = yield ndb.get_async(msg.author)
  raise tasklet.Return('On %s, %s wrote:\n%s' % (msg.when, acct.nick(), msg.body))

qry = Messages.query().order(-Message.when)
outputs = qry.map(callback, limit=20)
for output in outputs:
  print output
```

The callback function is called for each entity returned by the query, and it can do whatever operations it needs (using `_async` methods and `yield` to do them asynchronously), returning the result when it's done. Because the callback is a tasklet, and uses yield to make the asynchronous calls, NDB can run multiple instances of it in parallel, and even batch up some operations.

Comment: i don't think i can use map because i use ndb.get_multi() on a list of keys i already know (or at least i didn't see any doc about using map with ndb.get_multi()).

Comment: i think there are a few typos or maybe old docs: ndb.get_async(msg.author) should be msg.author.get_async() and tasket.Return is ndb.Return ... ?!

Comment: acct is a Future object so trying the string formatting in Return raises AttributeError: 'Future' object has no attribute 'nick'

Comment: If you're using `ndb.get_multi` to fetch a set of references, you can do individual async gets inside the tasklet. NDB will batch them up as necessary. You're right about the second issue; for the third, `acct` is not a future object - yielding a future in a tasklet returns the object itself.

Comment: i added an edit2 to my question. i have a tasklet now that is faster but it still takes around 6s for around 400 assets. is the code ok?

Comment: @aschmid00 Well, if the async fetch is the only db operation you need to do, sure, that should work. You shouldn't be calling `_get_kind` directly, though - call `.key.kind()` - and your return value really shouldn't have the same name as the function it's in.

Comment: i agree with the naming. the code above is not my real code so there could be typos. what if i would need to execute a function for each obj in ndb.get_multi_async() before raising ndb.Return?

Comment: @aschmid00 Then you should use `ndb.map`, as I suggested earlier.

Comment: but there is no ndb.map function and there is no such thing like Key.kind()

Comment: @aschmid00 From the documentation: "Take note that although get_async() returns a Future, the tasklet framework causes the yield expression to return the Future's result to variable acct."

Answer (score 0):

The pipeline API is overkill for what you want to do. Is there any reason why you couldn't just use a taskqueue?

Use the initial request to get all of the entity keys, and then enqueue a task for each key having the task execute the 2 functions per-entity. The concurrency will be based then on the number of concurrent requests as configured for that taskqueue.